# Can BLE on an IOT device autopair/autoconnect with Android / iPhone without any passcode?

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, pairing

I am experimenting with Raspberry Pi as an IOT device. And trying to understand the BLE concept.

And the scenario is the IOT device can be used to open doors, or access lifts (i'ved seen in hotels). So I'm not clear how the design of BLE interaction works and to identify the mobile device (Android/iPhone).

So first is, can the IOT device use BLE to autopair/autoconnect to Android / iPhone without any passcode ? The reason asking this is if its possible, then we could possible do some data exchanges to authenticate the mobile device. Otherwise, how is it done to identify the mobile BLE device (both Android & iPhone)

Comment: Yes.  You can use Just Works pairing with BLE.  This is quite common

Comment: What about BLE Secure Simple Pairing ? seems like an upgrade with Just Works. Do you recommend that instead ? Would it work without PIN code ?

Comment: Yes. SSP has no pin code. Generally BLE peripherals do not have a bonding process at all, you just connect and use GATT. This would certainly be the case in an access control scenario. There are several products available on the market that use BLE for access control. HID Origo, Kisi, Brivo, OpenPath, Elatec and many more

Comment: What method do you think these commercial products use for autoconnect ? Just Works or SSP or something else ? As I understand it, one more setting is BT security level needs to be set to None/0 for no passcode method to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few different pairing methods including

- Just Works: Pairing is mostly automatic, meaning this is unauthenticated. Your application will need to authenticate
- Passkey Entry
- Numeric Comparison
- Out of band (OOB): Use NFC or some other non-BLE method to authenticate

The proper selection of these option depends on the IO capabilities of each device. Per the Bluetooth Core Spec (v5.4):
[image: IO capabilities and pairing method (1)]
[image: IO capabilities and pairing method (2)]

So if Raspberry Pi is accessing a door or something with no straighforward IO, you are stuck with using Just Works per the NoInput NoOutput Responser row, unless there is an out-of-band method for authenticating. It sounds like OOB is not relevant to you, meaning some message exchanges after connecting would be necessary.

If you simply want to identify the device without authentication, this is done through the advertising data of the peripheral (e.g. a door lock). Often a peripheral's advertising data includes a Local Name or a UUID that announces itself and allows the central (e.g. Raspberry Pi) to scan and identify it. But something like a door lock would require an application level exchange after connecting in order to securely interact with it.

If you want to understand advertising and connections, check out the LightBlue or NRF Connect apps. They scan for peripherals and can connect to them. I also wrote a [blogpost](https://punchthrough.com/manage-ble-connection/) to help on-ramp someone new to BLE to understanding advertising and connections.

Comment: Thank you very much, that is very helpful. We will attempt BLE autoconnect. I need to ask, is BLE Secure Simple Pairing possible then ? since its not shown in the table. It is said to be better than Just Works. I think using application level exchanges you mentioned could be used to secure the identification process. Could you confirm on BLE Secure Simple Pairing ?

Comment: Maybe you'll want to check this blog series: https://www.bluetooth.com/blog/bluetooth-pairing-part-1-pairing-feature-exchange/
Secure Simple Pairing is the overall name for the process. From Core spec V5.4, page 266:
> Secure Simple Pairing utilizes FIPS-approved algorithms (SHA-256, HMACSHA-256 and the P-192 elliptic curve) and four association models: Just 
Works, Numeric Comparison, Passkey Entry and Out-Of-Band (see Section 
5.2)